# laravel database connection error 1049

Tags: database, laravel, connection

I am using Laravel 5 and I am having problems with my database conneciton:

Here is my database.php file:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'my_scene'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'engine'    => null,
    ],
```

and here is my .env file:

> DB_HOST=localhost
>
> DB_DATABASE=my_scene
>
> DB_USERNAME=root
>
> DB_PASSWORD=null

however when i then run "php artisan migrate" i get the error

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'my_scene'

I have tried php artisan cache:clear and config:cache and also reloaded my xampp controller but it has not worked.

any ideas?

Comment: I think it's trying with null as a string. Try `DB_PASSWORD=` and  `env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), ` instead

Comment: still giving me an error 1049 unknown database

Comment: Try to unset DB_PASSWORD (remove) from .env file and set `env('DB_PASSWORD', null)`. I've never try with a null password. I thought it was empty, nor null.

Comment: still saying unknown database

Answer (score 4):

Its not a connection error.

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'my_scene'
```

indicates you've successfully connected to MySQL server. but there is no database matching the name `my_scene`

You can create a database by using any of the following methods.

### 1. MySQL Command Line Utility

You just have to create a database by executing this MySQL statement in your terminal

```
CREATE DATABASE my_scene;
```

read [Creating Database via terminal](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/create-a-mysql-database-on-linux-via-command-line/)

### 2. PHPMyAdmin

If you've a MySQL GUI i.e PHPMyAdmin you can easily create a database.

Refer to [this article](http://webvaultwiki.com.au/(S(iungfwenvz2f5c55pioeinil))/Default.aspx?Page=Create-Mysql-Database-User-Phpmyadmin&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to read more about creating databases via PHPMyAdmin

### 3. Laravel's Command Line Utility [Artisan]

Maybe the simplest option using Laravel's `artisan` utility

1. Open Your terminal
2. Run `php artisan tinker`
3. Use the following snippet to create your database

   `DB::connection()->statement('CREATE DATABASE my_scene');`

Comment: what is the command for creating a database in terminal? also i am simply trying to access the user db that is already created in laravel

Comment: You've to create a database before running you migrations. see my updated answer to read how you can create a database via Terminal by using MySQL command line utility

Comment: i mam simply trying to migrate the create users table and the create password table that are preinstalled with laravel

Comment: to create users table first you need a database and this is what you've to create.

Comment: checkout the 3rd option if you are not familiar with MySQL and PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

In your config file, make DB_PASSWORD equal the empty string "" and leave the DB_PASSWORD out of the .env file.

Or, you can remove the null and leave the DB_PASSWORD as empty:

```
DB_PASSWORD=
```

This will signify an empty string for the password.

Comment: Does the database exist?

Comment: what do you mean does that database exist?

Comment: You need to create the database before you can successfully connect to it. Laravel doesn't create that for you.

Comment: but does the user table and password reset table not count as pre installed tables?

Comment: Tables are not databases. You must create a database first, then use Laravel to create the users and password resets table.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error and I was able to solve it.

I'm using `Laravel 7` with WampServer 3.2 and I have installed two databases `MySQL` and `Maria DB`

So I created the database with MySQL using `PhpMyAdmin` 
and I was getting the `1049` error when using `php artisan migrate`

Then I created the database with `MariaDB` (using `PhpMyAdmin`) and the Migration was successful 
so `Laravel` was trying to connect to `MariaDB` database but there was no database (with the correct connection values)